# how to change backgound image using sass on focus of another element

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

There is a class `inputBlog` which has a background image. I need to change this background image on focus an input element.

But couldn't find out how to do in SASS.

JSX:

```
  <div className={styles.inputBlog}>
    some text
  </div>
</div>
<div className={styles.inputSection}>
  <input type="text"
```

Existing CSS:

```
.inputBlog {
  background: url('image.png')
}
   
.inputSection {
  input {
    border-left: 0;
    
    &:focus {
      .inputBlog {
         background: url('differentimage.png');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you structure your question better. You says you want to change the background of the parent of the input, but the only background styling is for inputBlog which is not the parent of the input

Comment: @UdenduAbasili hi, does it better now ?

Comment: the `background: url('diffirent image');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the way your JSX currently is, you cannot use CSS or sass to change the inputBlog when you focus on the input . The only thing you can use is JavaScript. So do something like this where I add onFocus and onBlur which basically check  when you focus into and focus out of the input component respectively. The Image Path represents the image you wanted to use in the CSS/sass. Since you only posted part of your JSX i am just calling this one Component so use the one that you actually have

```
import React from 'react';
import Image1 from 'image path';
import Image2 from 'image path';

const Component= () => {
    const [focused, setFocused] = React.useState(false)
const onFocus = () => setFocused(true)
const onBlur = () => setFocused(false)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const inputBlog = document.querySelector('.inputBlog')
    if(focused){
      inputBlog.style.background = `url(${Image1})` 
   }else{
    inputBlog.style.background = `url(${Image2})` 
}


  }, [focused]);

 return (
        <div className='inputBlog' >
              some text
             </div>
         </div>
           <div className='inputSection'>
                 <input
                    type="text"
                    onFocus={onFocus} 
                    onBlur={onBlur}
    );

}
```